# Why showing that $\bar{xy} \in \bar{P}^{2}$ but that no power of $\bar{y}$ lies in $\bar{P}^2$ shows that it is a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

Let $R = \mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ and let bars denote passage to $ \mathbb Q[x,y,z] / (xy - z^2).$ Prove that $\overline{P} = (\bar{x}, \bar{z})$ is a prime ideal. Show that $\overline{xy} \in \overline{P}^2$ but that no power of $\bar{y}$ lies in $\overline{P}^2.$ (This shows $\overline{P}$ is a prime ideal whose square is *not* a primary ideal).

**My question is about the second part of the question:**

Why showing that $\bar{xy} \in \bar{P}^{2}$ but that no power of $\bar{y}$ lies in $\bar{P}^2$ shows that it is a prime ideal ? Does not that the definiton required either a $x \in \overline{P}^2$ or $y \in \overline{P}^2$? what exactly is the definition of Prime ideal in case of $\bar{P}^{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two claims being made:

$\bar P$ is prime and

$(\bar P)^2$ is not primary.

> Why showing that $\bar{xy} \in \bar{P}^{2}$ but that no power of $\bar{y}$ lies in $\bar{P}^2$ shows that it is a prime ideal ?

The answer is "It doesn't. It shows $(\bar P)^2$ is not primary. You are mixing up the halves of the task. They did not offer a hint on how to show $\bar P$ is prime."

Comment: I see thank you!

Comment: Also, we know that $\bar{x} \notin \overline{P}^2$ that is the remainder of the condition to show that $\overline{P}^2$ is not primary (but it was not stated clearly). Am I correct?

Comment: @Emptymind Yes, to show it is not primary you'd need to demonstrate both that $x\notin P^2$ and no power of $y$ in $P^2$.